# Uncertain on how to design for conditional one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, schema

I have lots of different types of calendars. Lets say, blue calendars and red calendars. I have a table representing my blue calendars. And a table representing my red calendars.

Blue calendars and red calendars are completely different and have very different attributes. That's why I have them in separate tables.

Now, I want another table that represents calendars. The idea being that I can simply expose a calendar ID in my api and I will be able to map that ID back to either a red or blue calendar.

The problem I have is I have no idea how to structure the calendar table. Should I have two foreign key columns - one of which will always be null because a calendar cannot be red and blue. Or should I have a 'type' column and a calendar_id column and therefore I will know which table the calendar_id is relating to?

I imagine that I will need three tables of some sort. One for each type of calendar and one to link them. I'm just not sure of the correct way to structure the link table.

Or - am I thinking about this completely wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: One table for all calendars with "color" (discriminator) field.

Comment: I have updated the question to make this more clear. Blue calendars and red calendars are completely different and have very different attributes. That's why I have them in separate tables.

Comment: As long as they are all calendars they should be in the same table.

Comment: But if they have different attributes, and if I add more calendars in the future with even more attributes. I could end up with a table with many many columns. A lot of which will be null.

Comment: If you keep your data properly normalized you should not.

Comment: This is a faq. Google stackoverflow.com about database/sql subtypes/subtyping. It's frequently posed as "fk/relationship/association to two/multiple tables" because of when another table involves the supertype, ie values from multiple subtypes.

Answer (score 1):

You should have two table, one for represent calendar structure and other for color structure.

Calendar table:

```
IdCalendar
IdColor
SOME OTHER ATTRB
```

Color Table:

```
IdColor
Color
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am pretty sure I will need three tables. Blue calendars and red calendars are completely different and have very different attributes. That's why I have them in separate tables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you tell us which is the different between them?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a CalendarKind table with:

- id_calendarKind
- name

And then add to your all calendar tables a new column id_calendarKind

Comment: This makes sense. So in the calendar table I will have the id_calendarKind column and a calendarID column. The calendarID column will then represent a different table dependant on the id_calendarKind column?

Comment: My solution was a little different but yours works just fine. What i understand from your comment: you have N different kinds of calendar tables and you want to create a CalendarKind table and a table( id_calendar, id_calendarKind) to store relations between them.

Answer (score 0):

If your calendar table is a parent table, you should establish its own calendarid and make its primary key column to be foreign key columns in each child table(red or blue)